# WPF Sub-group highlighting

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, highlighting

I am building a tool to edit multiple database objects at the same time and am curious to get you guys' thoughts on a highlighting scheme.
In my `ViewModel`, I have a collection, `Juris`, of `Jurisdictions` that are associated with ANY of the items a user selected to edit.  I also have a sub-collection of Jurisdictions shared by ALL the selected items, "CommonJuris".  My question is: Is there a simple way I can populate a `ListBox` with the full collection, and highlight items that are in the sub-collection?
At the moment I have a bool property, `IsCommon`, in my `Jurisdiction Model`.  I really don't want this in the `Model`, but I haven't found a better solution yet. `Jurisdiction` doesn't have a `ViewModel`, as this would be the only thing in it.

Here's my XAML for the ListBox itself:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource JuriAndTT}"
      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Juris}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And the Style:

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="JuriAndTT">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCommon}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="PowderBlue"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you answered this yourself -- you haven't created a view-model because it would have only one property; instead you have polluted your model with that property.

You have to weigh the two and determine whether you are more comfortable with `IsCommon` in the model or with the overhead of creating a view-model.

There are some other approaches you could take, with creative use of attached properties or converters, but they will be more convoluted and difficult than just implementing the view-model.